# Nagios Core Influxdb not showing nagios data

Tags: linux, debian, grafana, influxdb, nagios

I have followed this guide:

https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-performance-graphs-using-influxdb-nagflux-grafana-histou-802.html#Nagflux_Config

Already have pnp4nagios running on the server (Debian 9). But I can't get any further, busy for weeks to try to get this fixed.

I am stuck at this point:

**Verify Nagflux Is Working**

Execute the following query to verify that InfluxDB is being populated with Nagios performance data:

```
curl -G "http://localhost:8086/query?db=nagflux&pretty=true" --data-urlencode "q=show series"
```

When I execute that command I get this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

Already done this on another distro (CentOS 8), still not results.

But when I execute this command (earlier in the documentation)

```
curl -G "http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true" --data-urlencode "q=show databases"
```

This works:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "databases",
                    "columns": [
                        "name"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "_internal"
                        ],
                        [
                            "nagflux"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can add the InfluxDB datasource succesfully in Grafana but I can not select any data when I try so select it from the field "FROM".

It's only showing:

- Default
- Autogen

So I am very curious what am I doing wrong, normally the documentation from Nagios support works very good.

Thank you big time for reading my issue :).

Answer (score 0):

As you already have PNP4Nagios installed, https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-using-grafana-with-pnp4nagios-803.html would be more apropriate solution for you.

/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg has different host_perfdata_file_processing_command when you try to fill influxdb (with nagflux) instead of using Grafana with PNP4Nagios.

Comment: I know, but I really need Influxdb, pnp4nagios does not give nice graphics as influxdb and does not support alerting (influxdb does). So the best way to archieve this is to uninstall pnp4nagios and install influxdb? For me the best solution would be a second server with influxdb on it and pulling it into Grafana or do I need a second nagios server then? Any ideas how to archieve this goal are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another server. I have Nagios Core, InfluxDB, Nagflux, Histou and Grafana working on same machine.
And you don't have to uninstal PNP4Nagios, just stop & disable service on boot: `systemctl stop npcd.service && systemctl disable npcd.service`.

After that you have to edit `nagios.cfg` according to: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-performance-graphs-using-influxdb-nagflux-grafana-histou-802.html#Nagios_Command_Config to change `host_perfdata_file_processing_command value`, and change format of `*_perfdata_file_template`.

Then define `process-host-perfdata-file-nagflux` & `process-service-perfdata-file-nagflux` commands in `commands.cfg`.

If you did like described above, after minute you should see changes in your nagflux database.
Install influxdb-client, then:

```
influx
use nagflux
SELECT * FROM METRICS
```

You should see your database loading :)